# appium installation in ubuntu 18.04 no guidance

Tags: 18.04

I have been facing error in terminal like failed in chromedriver installation permission denied every time 
eventhough there is no clear guidance to do appium setup for ubuntu 18.04
so can someone provide an detailed structure on how and what are needed to be done to get it right..
the errors are new and not found on any other discussions too.

Comment: Please show complete error messages.